# Class storage guarantee in c++

Tags: c++, class, storage

I have a struct `Foo` from an external API library, which is in C, and above which I am writing a C++ interface.

So I have a class like this:

```
class ClassFoo
{
public:
    ClassFoo(const Foo * ptr) : ptr(ptr) { }
    ~ClassFoo();

    bool method1();
    int method2();
    ... (other methods)
private:
    const Foo * ptr;
}
```

Then, the external library defines another `struct Bar` which is a collection of `Foo`s, a method for getting the number of foos, and a method for retrieving an array of `Foo*` pointers:

```
int APIbarGetNumFoos(const Bar* ref);
void APIbarGetFoos(const Bar* ref, int maxSize, const Foo* foos[]);
```

I define a `ClassBar` like this:

```
class ClassBar
{
public:
    ClassBar(const Bar * ptr) : ptr(ptr) { }
    ~ClassBar();

    std::vector<ClassFoo> getFoos();

    ... (other methods)
private:
    const Bar * ptr;
}
```

Now the question : for memory & speed efficiency, I want to avoid allocating an array of `Foo*` to call the C API, then copy everything to the result vector.

Does C++ guarantees that `ClassFoo` instance only contains a `Foo*` pointer, and that its size is the size of a pointer, if I do not use any virtual methods (to avoid the vtables), so that I can define `getFoos()` like that:

```
std::vector<ClassFoo> ClassBar::getFoos()
{
    int size = APIbarGetNumFoos(ptr);
    std::vector<ClassFoo> result(size);
    APIbarGetFoos(ptr, size, (const Foo**) &result[0]);
    return result;
}
```

In other words, can I be sure that an array of `ClassFoo` will be in memory strictly the same as an array of `Foo*` ?

Thanks!

Etienne

Comment: An array of `ClassFoo` definitely won't be the same as an array of `Foo`. Do you mean the same as an array of `Foo*`?

Comment: Perhaps not guaranteed, but it should work on most implementations. Besides, you need to cast to `Foo**`, not `Foo*`.

Comment: Yup, I missed two `*` as I actually has a FooRef struct that trivially contains the Foo*, but I simplified the example... Fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the responses and comments, it appears that:

- It works on a recent gcc (4.8) and seems to work on main compilers
- One can guarantee this at compilation by using: (tested on gcc 4.8)

  `static_assert(! std::is_pod<ClassFoo>::value, "Foo* cannot be copied to ClassFoo");`
- It may bee less restrictive and still OK to use `is_standard_layout` instead of `is_pod`

Answer (score 3):

You can use static_assert:

```
static_assert(sizeof(Foo*) == sizeof(ClassFoo), "Sizes don't match!");
```

Then you'll have a compile-time error if the sizes don't match.  Purists may say this is still not strict enough, but in practice it's probably OK.

By the way, here:

```
(const Foo*) &result[0]
```

I think you might mean:

```
reinterpret_cast<const Foo**>(&result[0]);
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` will not guarantee that the pointer address is the same, which will lead to a crash in such cases. `static_cast` is the correct way, I guess

Answer (score 1):

I believe the short answer is: Yes!

C++ objects (that don't contain vtables) are just like C structs, and methods are just like C functions with an inplicit `this` parameter.

I'm not sure whether that's true if you have RTTI enabled though.

Comment: Only if he doesn't define ctors, etc. [PODs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c).

Comment: ctors don't affect class size; virtual functions do.

Comment: Constructors prevent a class being described as POD because it makes them hard to use in unions, but they don't have any actual presence in the object, I think.

Comment: If the class is not a POD it might still be trivially copyable. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable

Comment: Also, the concept relevant *here* is standard_layout (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout), which is also independent of non-virtual methods, ctors, dtors, etc.

Comment: I don't believe the layout is significant. The question is whether an array of pointers to C struct is more efficient than an array of objects that contain the same pointer.

Comment: @ams : actually, std::is_pod returns true even with a constructor, so this seems not true

Comment: @galinette: I believe it's possible to write a constructor for which that is not true.